# "Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type (ReactJS/MaterialUI)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I create a login button that onClick logs the user in and then the generated information is stored in the local storage, but I keep getting an "Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type. I am using reactJS to do so.

```
        // Global Navigation Bar

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import cognitoUtils from "lib/cognitoUtils";
import "assets/css/Base.css";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
import AccountCircleOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircleOutlined";
import AccountCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { session: state.session };
};

class SignInOut extends Component {
  onSignOut = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    cognitoUtils.signOutCognitoSession();
  };

  state = {
    on: true
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      on: !this.state.on
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="profile_button" onClick={this.toggle}>
          {this.state.on && (
            <div>
              {this.props.session.isLoggedIn ? (
                <div>
                  <a
                    className="Home-link"
                    href="/home"
                    onClick={this.onSignOut}
                  >
                    <Tooltip title="Profile">
                      <Avatar className="profile_icon">
                        <AccountCircleIcon className="profile_icon_in" />
                      </Avatar>
                    </Tooltip>
                  </a>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div>
                  <a
                    className="Home-link"
                    href={cognitoUtils.getCognitoSignInUri()}
                    onClick="/home"
                  >
                    <Tooltip title="Profile">
                      <Avatar className="profile_icon">
                        <AccountCircleOutlinedIcon className="profile_icon" />
                      </Avatar>
                    </Tooltip>
                  </a>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignInOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing `String` type to onClick

```
 onClick="/home"
```

You need to pass a function as stated in the error. something like you did before

```
onClick={this.onSignOut}
```